# Create a pip server in python and give authentication

Tags: python, authentication, pip

I am dealing with python project and I have a 3rd party python package(called xp) need to be install by a pip server. I installed pip server using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install pip-python
```

Now I have to give the authentication part. As a example, if someone try to install xp using pip, they need to give their given username and password for authentication. After a successful log in We need to install xp package.

So please help me on this, guiding and advice appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: no one to give an answer for me????